# Python .exe PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

Tags: python, windows, exe, permission-denied, auto-py-to-exe

Here's the code for my *reprex*:

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader as rdr
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter as wtr

import os

SELF_PATH = os.path.dirname(__file__)
file_name = 'pdf_file'

in_path = fr'{SELF_PATH}\{file_name}.pdf'
assert os.path.isfile(in_path)
input = open(in_path, 'r+b')

reader = rdr(input, strict=False)
writer = wtr()

orientation = reader.getPage(0).get('/Rotate')

for pagenum in range(reader.numPages):
    page = reader.getPage(pagenum)
    page.rotateClockwise(180)
    writer.addPage(page)

out_path = fr'{SELF_PATH}\_{file_name}.pdf'
assert os.path.isfile(out_path)
output = open(out_path, 'wb')

writer.write(output)
output.close()
input.close()
```

From this, I used **auto-py-to-exe** to build a one-directory .exe. Then I opened **cmd** as an administrator, navigated to the .exe's folder and attempted to run the executable. Here's the output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tab.py", line 11, in <module>
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\paulo\\OneDrive\\Pastas\\Python\\Personal\\DocReader\\tab\\pdf_file.pdf'
[25204] Failed to execute script 'tab' due to unhandled exception!
```

I am all out of ideas at this point, and I'd appreciate any thoughts.

Comment: Do you have that pdf file open in some other program?

Comment: Please post the error as text, not image.

Comment: @toyotaSupra sorry guys, rookie mistake!

Comment: @JohnGordon no, I don't :(

Comment: So, what are the permissions on that PDF file?

Comment: @RolandSmith I am thinking I have full permissions, since I can execute my program without any trouble normally. It's just when I turn it into an .exe that I get this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue. My antivirus was blocking file creation.

Additionally, I'd suggest sticking with python's standard syntax regarding files.

```
import os

SELF_PATH = os.path.dirname(__file__)
with open(f'{SELF_PATH}/{file_name}.pdf', 'wb') as output:
    output.write(output)
```